# what is effective algorithm of painting a white board as input

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, matrix

There is a M x N(M, N <= 50) board divided into unit squares. Each unit square is painted white. I try to paint some spaces black. Painting means selecting consecutive white squares(horizontal stroke or one vertical stroke) and paint them black. Using combination of horizontal strokes and vertical strokes in consecutive white squares, find minimum number of paintings.

I tried to solve it but I couldn't find a possible solution. Now, I want to know effective algorithm to solve it.

exam1) 
Given a 5x3 matrix as problem input,
'o' -> black
'x' -> white

o o o
  x o x
  o o o
  x o x
  o o o

answer) Minimum count of painting is 5.
paint (0,0 ... 0,2)
paint (2,0 ... 2,2)
paint (4,0 ... 4,2)
paint (1,1)
paint (3,1)

exam2) 
Given a 3x3 matrix,

o x o
  o o o
  o x o

answer) Minimum count of painting is 3.
paint (0,0 ... 2,0)
paint (1,1)
paint (0,2 ... 2,2)

exam3) 
Given a 3x3 matrix,

o o o
  o o o
  o x o

answer) Minimum count of painting is 3.
paint (0,0 ... 2,0)
paint (0,1 ... 1,1)
paint (0,2 ... 2,2)

exam4) 
Given a 3x3 matrix,

o x o
  x o o
  o x o

answer) Minimum count of painting is 4.
paint (0,2 ... 2,2)
paint (0,0)
paint (1,1)
paint (2,0)

Comment: Your problem description does not seem consistent with any of your examples.  Can you explain your examples?

Comment: The question can maybe be better understood by saying *"Using only a combination of purely horizontal and vertical strokes, what is the minimum number of strokes to paint over all zeroes in the grid?"*. Without painting over an `x` of course.

Comment: Thank you. update my post. It's little better.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is go through the possibilities, counting each time you preform an action, and take the min of the `count`s

```
f(grid,count)
    for each square in grid
        if square is a circle // i.e. 'o'
            return min(g(grid with vertical stroke,count+1),
                       g(grid with horizontal stroke,count+1))
    return count
```

I represent

```
o o o
x o x
o o o
x o x
o o o
```

by

```java
boolean arr [][] = {
            {false,false,false},
            {true,false,true},
            {false,false,false},
            {true,false,true},
            {false,false,false}
    };
```

In java i have:

```java
// return copy of arr
static boolean[][] copy(boolean arr[][]){
    boolean[][] c = new boolean[arr.length][arr[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        c[i] = arr[i].clone();
    return c;
}

// select consecutive squares horizontal stroke at (i,j)
static boolean[][] leftRight(boolean arr[][],int i, int j){
    boolean[][] c = copy(arr);

    // right
    int k = j;
    while (true){
        if(k==arr[0].length || c[i][k]){
            break;
        }
        c[i][k] = true;
        k++;
    }

    // left
    k = j;
    while (true){
        if(k==-1 || c[i][k]){
            break;
        }
        c[i][k] = true;
        k--;
    }
    c[i][j] = true;
    return c;
}

// select consecutive squares vertical stroke at (i,j)
static boolean[][] upDown(boolean arr[][],int i, int j){
    boolean[][] c = copy(arr);

    // down
    int k = i;
    while (true){
        if(k==arr.length || c[k][j]){
            break;
        }
        c[k][j] = true;
        k++;
    }

    // up
    k = i;
    while (true){
        if(k==-1 || c[k][j]){
            break;
        }
        c[k][j] = true;
        k--;
    }
    c[i][j] = true;
    return c;
}


static int g(boolean arr[][], int count){
    // for each square in grid
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
            // if false then select square
            // and try horizontal and vertical stroke
            // take the min of the 2
            if (!arr[i][j]) {
                return Math.min(g(leftRight(arr,i,j),count+1),g(upDown(arr,i,j),count+1));
            }
        }
    }
    return  count;
}


public static void main(String args[]){
    /*
    o o o
    x o x
    o o o
    x o x
    o o o
    */
    boolean arr [][] = {
            {false,false,false},
            {true,false,true},
            {false,false,false},
            {true,false,true},
            {false,false,false}
    };
    System.out.println(g(arr,0));

}
```

Output:

`5`

Comment: Thx. In a little while, I will try.